# Cross-platform package manager for packages *not* on CTAN

Tags: packages, installing, miktex, texlive, ctan

I do not want to reinvent the wheel, so perhaps you could help me find a tool that fits my needs.

### Background

As far as I know, it takes some time to get a LaTeX package available on CTAN. And some people (including me) develop packages on Github etc. So it would be nice to have a tool (just like `apt-get` or `tmgr`) which can manage LaTeX packages outside of CTAN.

### Requirements

- **Cross-platform** The tool should run on all major operating systems and should be compatible with TeXLive and MiKTeX.
- **Github support** Download and update LaTeX-packages from services like Github / Sourceforge / Google Code.
- **Command-line interface** There should be options to *update* all installed packages or *install* a package from a given URL

Comment: If there exists nothing like this, I will develop such a tool, so feel free to add your thoughts `:)`

Comment: If this not what [TL-contrib](http://tlcontrib.metatex.org/) strives at solving?

Comment: In my opinion there is no need for such a tool. Every author can upload the package and it will be available via the installed package manager in 2 or 3 days. The normal user will use the installed packages from the LaTeX distribution. To create a package for CTAN you can use tools like `ctanify`.

Comment: It's absolutly no problem to get anything on CTAN. It takes 1-3 days, thanks to the CTAN team. I uploaded something yesterday and it was available at the core server a few hours later. The real problem is that developers do not or do not want to release on CTAN. The CTAN team would be happy to install all TeX related software to also get it into TeXLive and MiKTeX. so please, release on CTAN. It's just uploading a zip file.

Comment: Some time ago, I forked the `circuitikz`-package on github and made two little modifications (added two more symbols I needed). I think that is not enough to upload it to CTAN, although it is something other users might need as well. So AFAIK, there is no possibility for me to allow other users to use my modifications?
@MartinHeller: Thank you, that was a very useful link!

Comment: @ralfix In that case you should contact the maintainer of `circuitikz` and ask him/her to include your symbols. If he/she is not willing to include, create your own package. But not a simple file copy. Load `circuitikz` in your package with `\RequirePackage` to profit from updates of `circuitikz` and add your symbols. Upload to CTAN. Why should that be a problem,as you said other user might need it as well.

Comment: The problem with 'a general tool' is that you need to know about the structure for each package. TeX Live (and I guess MiKTeX) handle that with scripts which have several standard set ups plus custom actions. However, you can't do that and say 'this tool will work for an arbitrary package'.

Comment: @ralfix: The package `capt-of` contains one relevant line. Or the package `indentfirst` has two lines.

Comment: A tool doing this, could be nice *but* CTAN is the central network where all users search for packages. If now packages are provided by CTAN, github etc. it will be hard to figure out, which package to get from where. I also have a problem with the idea of getting package-updates from something like github. These are development versions often containing errors. Only stable versions are uploaded to CTAN so you can expect them to be stable and working.

Comment: Thank you very much for your contribution and for encouraging me to upload my packages to CTAN. They are coming soon `;)`. One more use-case I could think of are "non-worldwide" packages, e.g. for use in a work group which would have low to no use for the "normal" TeX user. But as there are packages for university papers, magazines etc. this should not be the main reason for such a tool. I think I was just a bit "scared" to contribute to the world of LaTeX, with my name everywhere, writing good documentation, etc... *Thank you*

Answer (score 2):

To create such a manager the biggest problem is the following: *How to convert from arbitrary layouts (as created by the authors) automatically to TDS (TeX Directory Standard) layout.*

There is a partial solution which we use when pulling from CTAN into TeX Live, it is a script called `ctan2tds` which knows a lot about many different packages and how to convert them to TDS layout. It even has an automatic mode if nothing special is specified. This automatic mode works quite well for simple packages, but no way for slightly involved packages.

Now for the super-tlmgr: There are several problems to be overcome:

- inclusion/extension of ctan2tds: this is probably the easiest part
- teach the super-tlmgr how to access a variety of sources (git, svn, zip, tar.gz, flat files, ...)
- make it platform-independent (good luck! I know how hard it is on Windows)

That said, it is not impossible. I envision a tlmgr extension that includes the ctan2tds code base, and in addition the user-mode patches so that one can install into arbitrary trees. The super-tlmgr would download the package from whatever source, try to run ctan2tds code on in, and put it into a temporary TDS folder and present the outcome to the user, offering to install or drop.

Of course, version checks, upgrades, etc etc might be problematic in this case.

Last thing: I don't think that *I* will ever have time to work on that. And there is another thing, namely that the ctan2tds code needs a rework and streamlining ...