# Error: File baposter.cls not found

Tags: ieee-style

There is an error while creating poster in latex.
The error is ,

> Blockquote File baposter.cls not found

Answer (score 1):

you have to get the class yourself, since the author keeps it on a private site, rather than ctan (tex live and miktex get their stuff from ctan).

it's very easy to find baposter.cls using google, which gives [the author’s site](http://www.brian-amberg.de/uni/poster/)

Comment: My apologies for hijacking this answer to get into contact, but [@Speravir thinks you could have something to contribute](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161318/#comment380810_161318) over at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/161318/17423.  Your username is just a *very* happy coincidence. :-)